# Use TokeParser in perl to extract a value from a self contained tag

Tags: perl, html-parsing

What I'm trying to do sounds really easy but somehow I'm struggling with it for several hours now, so please point me in the right direction:

I've got some html that looks like this:

```
<img src="random.jpg" class="someClass" id="someId" alt="test" />
```

and currently I cannot match this with this code:

```
my $tp = HTML::TokeParser->new(\$rawHTML) || die "Cant't open: $!";
while (my $token = $tp->get_token){
  my $ttype = shift @{ $token };
  if($ttype eq "S"){
    my($tag, $attr, $attrseq, $rawtxt) = @{ $token };
    if ($tag eq "img"){
      if(($attr->{'class'} eq "someClass")&&($attr->{'id'}eq "someId")){
        my $alttext = $attr->{'alt'};
        print "AltText: $alttext";
        ...
        }
      }        
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that TokeParser just ignores self contained tags <.../>. 
Why? I've searched long and hard for a solution for this and would really appreciate any help to make it work with TokeParser or any other Perl module...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't ignore anything:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use HTML::TokeParser;
use YAML;

my $html = q{<img src="random.jpg" class="someClass" id="someId" alt="test"/>};

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser->new( \$html );

while (my $token = $parser->get_token) {
    print Dump $token;
}
```

Output:

```
---
- S
- img
- /: /
  alt: test
  class: someClass
  id: someId
  src: random.jpg
-
  - src
  - class
  - id
  - alt
  - /
- '<img src="random.jpg" class="someClass" id="someId" alt="test"/>'
```

BTW, [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) gives you a better interface.

Comment: Indeed, it worked beautifully.  Looked like PingLu was trying to grab the alt text within the img tag.  Perhaps not just that...

Comment: Hmh... yeah, it's working, copying my other code into this works too. Somethings seems to break when I put the whole HTML file into it. After making a dump it seems that TokeParser is jumping several opening and closing tags, so I still can't access the <img .../> tag... very strange.
But I'm fed up with it right now and will look into Mojo::DOM or Treebuilder. Thanks anyway! I'd accept the answer, it should work with it. I'm stumbled by why it won't for my specific html... unfortunately I can't supply the original HTML Code since it contains some confidential data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're interested in capturing the alt text `"test"` in your html snippet, given `someClass` and `someId`.  If so, try the following:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Web::Query qw();

my $w = Web::Query->new_from_html(<<'HTML');
<img src="random.jpg" class="someClass" id="someId" alt="test" />
HTML

my @altText = $w->find('img[class="someClass"][id="someId"]')->attr('alt');

say @altText;
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd use Web::Query if there is no other way since everything else is relying on TokeParser and the tag <img ../> is recurring more than once. So combining the tokens and the web:query->find would be really messy. Nevertheless I'll keep that in my mind. :)